# Give a stroke to svg objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, border, fabricjs

Good day everyone,

I was trying to give a svg object in fabric a stroke around the bounding box. Unfortunately

```
obj.set({
  'stroke': 'red',
  'strokeWidth': 2
});
```

won't work, even after updating with.

```
obj.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```

All other attributes as in fill or angle seem to work. Did someone has come across this problem and know how to solve it?

Thank you already
Sebastian

Edit:
This is how I am loading the svg:

```
var group = [];    
var loadedObjects;

fabric.loadSVGFromURL(

            'bla.svg', 

            function(objects, options) {
                loadedObjects = new fabric.Group(group);
            }, 

            function(item, object) {
                object.set('id', item.getAttribute('id'));
                group.push(object);
            }
);
```

Comment: is your obj a Path? If yes coul you provide the full code of your imported svg?

Comment: Hello @Sebastian, your code is right, the problem probably is related of the svg, add your imported svg markup and we can resolve your problem for sure; BTW take a look to your other question, is solved

Comment: Here you go: There is a couple, but it won't work with any of them, unfortunately: https://github.com/SebastianJvF/SebastianJvF.github.io/tree/master/img/buttons

Answer (score 2):

fabricjs does not support border drawing for group or pathGroup.
What you can do is load your svg as a pathgroup.
Once it is loaded create a rect with same width and height, give him same top and left. Stroke the rect and group them togheter:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(

            'bla.svg', 

            function(objects, options) {
                var svg = fabric.util.groupSvg(objects, options);
                var rect = new fabric.Rect({width:svg.width, height: svg.height, top:svg.top, left: svg.left, stroke: 'red', strokeWidth: 5});
                group = new fabric.Group([svg, rect]);
                canvas.add(group);
            }
);
```